# How to redirect Dojo Data grid cell values to another page?

Tags: java, html, dojo

I  have a dojo data grid.. it has 10 rows(cells) of values.. on clicking first row, it should get redirected to another page(html page) along with first row values. please help me to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply share data between two html-pages just like that. But you've got some options like using cookies or using php get arguments (`http://www.url.net?arg1=tada`) or whatnot.
Local databases (e.g. SQLite) could also help.

Or is the problem accessing the values of the cells?